# Check Sum Errors on Checkout

Tags: tortoisesvn

On a virtual host server, I have 1 repository that I can no longer checkout from a remote computer. Checkout works fine if I'm checking out on the server itself. All other repositories on the same virtual host server work without a problem, though none of them have as many files as this one.

When I check out on a remote computer, checkout goes a certain number of files, then starts displaying checksum errors, usually between 2 and 6 at a time. If I delete the checked out folder and try again with a new folder, it will stop after about the same number of files, and the collection of files with checksum errors is different from the previous checkout. Checking out on a different remote computer gets the same random results.

First try:

```
Error: Checksum mismatch for  
Error:  'C:\Users\jkorc\Documents\Projects\VHost\RoyalProvincial\Genealogy\Settle\settle.shtml':  
Error:   
Error:    expected:  b450dbef2a3ceb9542a4e22b4b3e50fe  
Error:      actual:  9454a4eb5afdbc215bffcc619f537fa3  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: Checksum mismatch for  
Error:  'C:\Users\jkorc\Documents\Projects\VHost\RoyalProvincial\Genealogy\Settle\lndnjv1.shtml':  
Error:   
Error:    expected:  e187d974743d0129a6c72413f205458c  
Error:      actual:  73c0b6aba9a9a42409e2cf7e6d043049  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: Checksum mismatch for  
Error:  'C:\Users\jkorc\Documents\Projects\VHost\RoyalProvincial\Genealogy\Settle\lndfraser.shtml':  
Error:   
Error:    expected:  151444dc294357ba42a640333c94b6f7  
Error:      actual:  900ffa360acd460773acbe1759578533  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: Checksum mismatch for  
Error:  'C:\Users\jkorc\Documents\Projects\VHost\RoyalProvincial\Genealogy\Settle\lndretn1.shtml':  
Error:   
Error:    expected:  6b8791dc78b0af936d6d7e70e11b69ee  
Error:      actual:  dd7af732663345c6401861c89331adea  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: Checksum mismatch for  
Error:  'C:\Users\jkorc\Documents\Projects\VHost\RoyalProvincial\Genealogy\Settle\lndrfa2.shtml':  
Error:   
Error:    expected:  7451fedd09e1f99adf4c4af2668c4942  
Error:      actual:  548f947ce54c697957daa4efa4192786  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: Checksum mismatch for  
Error:  'C:\Users\jkorc\Documents\Projects\VHost\RoyalProvincial\Genealogy\Settle\lndpwar3.shtml':  
Error:   
Error:    expected:  f7fba4f2a3a468df6c4948eaa034e119  
Error:      actual:  0f3c2da13e55a7c0271743e7d145cfca  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: Checksum mismatch for  
Error:  'C:\Users\jkorc\Documents\Projects\VHost\RoyalProvincial\Genealogy\Settle\lndrhe1.shtml':  
Error:   
Error:    expected:  32cc673b06be5806bc6bc66000d5ec75  
Error:      actual:  5356175235c395577793e9fa9f0b9bb7
```

Second try:

```
Error: Checksum mismatch for  
Error:  'C:\Users\jkorc\Documents\Projects\VHost\RoyalProvincial\Genealogy\Settle\Petition_Teder_M_1795.shtml':  
Error:   
Error:    expected:  c29978209a203cd254c641bd931739e5  
Error:      actual:  e4042c36b5ff42a01eb890044d64b131  
Error: Additional errors:  
Error: Checksum mismatch for  
Error:  'C:\Users\jkorc\Documents\Projects\VHost\RoyalProvincial\Genealogy\Settle\lndbrng1.shtml':  
Error:   
Error:    expected:  6daeec06c6290557ca6b0de0d551fc43  
Error:      actual:  598d6bad86117e4cf8f384ed523800aa
```

I created a new repository of the same files on the same server. Same problem, except I start getting checksum errors after downloading only about a dozen files instead of a few hundred. The server is on Subversion 1.13.0, Tortoise is 1.13.1.

Any ideas what kind of problem I should be looking for?

Comment: try newer subversion server and TSVN 1.14.1: https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Comment: 1.14 is not available for the server in the MacPorts packaging system, which is what we use.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be that a certain folder has a corrupt checksum (for whatever reason).

Fist of all I'd check integrity of the SVN. Some instyructions can be found here:
https://www.darklaunch.com/fix-svnadmin-checksum-mismatch-while-reading-representation.html

There's quite some people experiencing this issue. The easy work around normally mentioned is to recreate the repo:

1. Copy the content to a temporary directory
2. Add the folder as new one to SVN
3. As the new content will get new checksums, those should be ok for all folders afterwards

If you want to do some direct editing, here's a post that corrected the SVN files successfully (use at own risk, make backups!)

https://maymay.net/blog/2008/06/17/fix-subversion-checksum-mismatch-error-by-editing-svnentries-file/

I once had strange behaviour when content on net packages had been capped as well. That was caused by the MTU (Maximum Transfer Unit). SVN seem to struggle here as well, so adjust the setting in your network infrastructure. Here's a link to a similar issue with SVN involved.

https://serverfault.com/questions/392881/tortoise-svn-repo-browser-checkout-over-vpn

As summary: To isolate the issue I would do the following steps:

A) See if the repo's SVN metadata is cause:

1. log to server
2. copy the repo as filesystem (without SVN data)
3. create a new repo with the files
4. connect svn client from other host. If all goes well the SVN metadata is corrupt

b) Check if it's host/network specific

- Do the same as A but from other host (= create the repo from there)
- List item

c) Check if network MTU is ok

- do check up to which size packets will be transferred ok (will not go into details as this is very OS/infrastructure related, but you'll find lot's of infos)
- note hops/VPNs/multiple routers/IPv4-IPv6 can all play into this

**Having written all that: Did you crosscheck behaviour with a second SVN client in the first place? Might be the first thing to do.**